# How do I insert an inline shape into a Manim Mathtex Mobject?

Tags: latex, inline, equation, tex, manim

In Manim I'm using MathTex to display equations.
I would like to allow variables in the equation to be shapes that I have constructed with other Manim functions.
And not just a Circle or Square but perhaps a composite shape made of multiple shapes using a VGroup.
So then the equation appears but in the relevant place(s) in the equation I would see the shape(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered your question on Discord - just copying what I think it is you are asking for here as well:

```py
class visualMath(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        math = MathTex(*r"\text{Red Circle}  +  \text{Green Square}  =  \text{Blue Square}".split("  "))
        redCircle = Circle(color=RED).scale_to_fit_width(math[0].width).move_to(math[0].get_center())        
        greenSquare = Square(color=GREEN).scale_to_fit_width(math[2].width).move_to(math[2].get_center())
        blueSquare = Square(color=BLUE).scale_to_fit_width(math[4].width).move_to(math[4].get_center()) 

        vis = VGroup(redCircle,math[1].copy(),greenSquare,math[3].copy(),blueSquare)
        self.play(Write(vis))       
        self.wait()
        self.play(ReplacementTransform(vis,math))
        self.wait()
```

[image: during the transition]